# Are disabling and uninstalling software "XY" the same question aka duplicate?

Tags: discussion

In my opinion disabling and uninstalling a piece of software are two different questions. One allows it to be "enabled" in the future, while the other removes it from the system all together. They often have the same goal, to stop the software from running, but can be entirely different processes to achieve and therefor have totally different answers.

I asked a question a long time ago about "Uninstalling Cortana" vs "Disabling It" which it was marked a duplicate to the "Disabling It" question. What is the community view on this? The question has about 10K Views and while it has -4 downvotes, I find myself getting +Rep all the time and the code has finally been made public on GitHub. But, not liking my answer because of using 3rd party softtware is not a reason to close as duplicate, its a reason to downvote the answer IMO.

[Uninstall Cortana Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/977425/uninstall-cortana-windows-10/977429?noredirect=1#comment1919887_977429)

Comment: You assume people didn’t like your question, but you failed to consider perhaps it was, because of how you asked it your question.  In other words the quality of the question.  The duplicate is better quality in every possible way.

Answer (score 6):

The closure was 2 1/2 years ago, and I was one of the close voters.  If you look at the edit history, close voting started before your last edit.  In the previous version, you had:

> While there is a thread on "disabling" Cortana, I couldn't share my answer due to my rep.

So it appeared to me, and I assume others, that you agreed that it was a duplicate; it was just a rep issue, the other question being protected.

Looking back on this now, I agree with the points here in your question and allquixotic's comments, so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Yeah i was new to superuser at the time, but i just re looked at it now that the code for the exe is available on git. Interesting discussion im happy to just learn and hear points of view.

Comment: How do you vote to re-open?  Do you need a certain amount of rep?

Comment: @Infiltrator, 3K to vote to close and reopen.  This got 3 reopen votes (5 needed), and stalled there, then the votes eventually expired.

Comment: I was just wondering that too, perhaps there are new ways for FCU and or dont require 3rd party download. Id love to see a powershell script answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your general question: **no**.

You can always have a daemon (or service, for Windows users) installed but just disabled and never running.  This is different to completely removing all of the files for running the daemon.

After writing the above, having just had a look at the specific question you referenced, I think that your question is not a duplicate of the one it is marked a duplicate.